# What to write in cookie?

Tags: php, security, session, cookies

I want my users to have secure session on my website. What must i store in cookie to recognise each user? 
Every time user logs in, cookie value must be changed.
P.S. I want to make a database with cookie values which link to user id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store a session ID in the cookie. That said, you should **NOT** have to do this yourself. Use [PHP sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), it does all the cookie handling for you.

Why do you need to store the session IDs in a database? If you need semi-temporary data to travel with the user during their session, you can use the `$_SESSION` variable for that. It is documented as part of the guide above.

PHP does not have native support for storing session IDs on the server in a database, you would have to write that yourself, or use a library that already provides that functionality, like [CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1310/Sessions).

Answer (score 5):

a [session id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)?

Comment: Indeed. Don't try to build your own session system, preexisting ones are just fine, even the one built into PHP.

Answer (score 2):

A cookie should be a [cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) that is used to reference server side state.  IE: A session id.   All web application platforms have their own session handler.  In php you just call `session_start()`  and then use the `$_SESSION[]` super global.